# node console.log() output array in one line

Tags: node.js, console.log

I use node `v10.6.0`.

Here's my codes:

```
console.log([{a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:2}])
console.log([{a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:2}])
```

the output is as following:

```
[ { a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1, b: 2 } ]
[ { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 1, b: 2 } ]
```

How can I make the second array output in one line, instead of spreading to multiple lines.

Comment: That's just how Node prints long objects...

Comment: @user202729, thanks for your remind. `JSON.stringify` solved my problem nicely!

Comment: `util.inspect` seems a little weird. As `util.inspect(...a long array...)` will output `'[ { a: 1, b: 2 },\n  { a: 1, b: 2 },\n  { a: 1, b: 2 },\n  ...`. Why include `\n` ...

Comment: @mCY There are parameters to control the output format for `util.inspect`. (read the documentation)

Comment: @user202729 got it : )

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Although the output is not exactly the same as if `console.log` is used, it's possible to use `JSON.stringify` to convert the array to a string, then print it:

```javascript
console.log(JSON.stringify(array))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9YVJRYaRtdnWhlqKOQZGVUq6NAW3bs/@T8vOL8nFS9nPx0Da9gfz@94pKizLz0zLRKDbBrNDX//wcA)

It cannot process circular structures, however.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest using the following:

```
console.log(util.inspect(array, {breakLength: Infinity}))
```

Plus, `util.inspect` has a bunch of extra options to format and limit the output:

https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options

Comment: There is another option `color: true` to keep the colors.

Comment: I get this:
C:\abc.js:91
 util.inspect(found, {breakLength: Infinity} )
 ^
ReferenceError: util is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\abc.js:91:2)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
[Finished in 0.1s]

Answer (score 5):

Why not using [`console.table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table) instead?

This give this nice table: https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9YVJRYaRtdnWhlqKOQZGVUq6NAW3bs/@T8vOL8nFS9ksSknFQNsAM0//8HAA

```
┌─────────┬───┬───┐
│ (index) │ a │ b │
├─────────┼───┼───┤
│    0    │ 1 │ 2 │
│    1    │ 1 │ 2 │
│    2    │ 1 │ 2 │
│    3    │ 1 │ 2 │
│    4    │ 1 │ 2 │
│    5    │ 1 │ 2 │
│    6    │ 1 │ 2 │
│    7    │ 1 │ 2 │
│    8    │ 1 │ 2 │
└─────────┴───┴───┘
```