# How can I change width of node console.log printing?

Tags: node.js, terminal

I am printing 2d arrays to the node terminal window but the width causes them to wrap across multiple lines. How can I change the width of the node print area? This is not solved by changing the terminal window columns or rows. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCWTT.png. Update: The problem is the printing of an array with node. If I print one string it will print a longer width so how do I change how node is giving arrays a default width of some kind regardless of number of elements?

For example:

`console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);`

will print

```
[

 1, 2, 3, 4,  5,

  6, 7, 8, 9, 10

];
```

Instead of putting it all on one line in node.

Comment: There are a few NPM modules for ASCII tables that are close to what you want.

Comment: Looks like the exact same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573010/node-console-log-output-array-in-one-line

Answer (score 3):

If your purpose is to visualize the two dimensional matrix, you may  use console.table as in example below

a = [[1, 3, 3, 4], [2, 7, 9, 12]];

console.table(a)

the output is as below

[image: the output is as below]

Answer (score 1):

Node.js prints objects in columns instead of one line due to the default console.log method in Node.js, which prevents it from printing deeply nested loops in a single line. It prints in columns to make it easier to read.

However there are two workarounds that you can utilise to print a single object on a single line.

1. `JSON.stringify()`

```
const obj = { a: 1, B: 2, x, 5, 7, Y };
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // prints on single line { a: 1, B: 2, x, 
5, 7, Y }
```

2. `util.inspect()`

```
const util = require('util');
const obj = {a: 6, b: 5};
console.log(util.inspect(obj, true, 1717, 8<9)); // this will print all on the same line
```